# How to achieve cake crust material?

Tags: materials

I'm making a Victoria sponge in Blender, and I'm not sure how to make the outside texture of the sponge cake. If a picture of a node setup could be provided, that'd be amazing. Thank you! :)

[image: Victoria Sponge w/ Crust Outlined]

Answer (score 5):

You could try something like this.

[image: Cake]

What I did was combine a Musgrave and a Noise texture and used that as a mix factor for the "Cake colors". I then took a lightened (softened) version of this mix and used that as a Bump Map of sorts. I also took the normal values from the Bump map, and the color data from the Noise Texture to provide the values for an Ambient Occlusion Node which I then colored dark brown and mixed with the original "cake color" to make the "darkened baked bits".

Lastly, I isolated the Z vector of a Gradient Texture (so it would lay flat) and "shaped" it with a ColorRamp to make a "top cap" mask which I would then use as a mix factor to apply the whites of yet another Noise Texture to the Cake by using a MixRGB node set to lighten. This makes the "icing sugar" on top.

Comment: Thank you Christopher Bennet! Looks great! :)

Answer (score 2):

I've also given a try, I've created the basic material, I've only used the *Noise Texture* for both the diffuse and the bump effects. For the basic material I've mixed two tones of orange, and created some bumps with the combination of 2 sizes of noise. The sugar is pure white, to create the sprinkle effect, I've mixed 2 sizes of noise. To keep the sugar in the desired area, I've used *Vertex Paint* and painted only the top of the cake, then used an *Input > Attribute* node, with the vertex paint group loaded, as a factor to mix with the basic material:

[image]
[image]